# How call a child's overriden method from other child?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have 3 classes :

```
ClassA
ClassB : ClassA 
ClassC : ClassA


public class A
{
    public virtual void chop(){

    }
}

public class B:A
{
    public override void chop(){
       print("b.chop");
    }
}

public class C:A
{
    public void call(){
       chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
    }
}
```

I want to call an overriden method on `C` from `B` !!!
Childs created at runtime and i can't know which one is where !
is there any way to let childs call each other ?
TNX

Comment: Maybe expand on your code, so we can see what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

From "override" in the C# docs

> An override method provides a new implementation of a member that is
>   inherited from a base class. The method that is overridden by an
>   override declaration is known as the overridden base method. The
>   overridden base method must have the same signature as the override
>   method. For information about inheritance, see Inheritance (C#
>   Programming Guide).

Your base class is A, so this would mean that you can only override methods from A. Thinking about it, which instance of C would you override?

That's presuming you are creating instances.

try

```
public class C:A
{
    public void call(){
        var b = new B();
        b.chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
    }
}
```

Comment: no , i mean thow childs (b,c) overrides A's method . and have same signature . now B wants to call what C has !!!

Comment: Need more code as I can't understand why you would want to call C from B. If C has a different implementation to B, then you probably want to extract to an interface or derive C from B, but the former is better

Comment: i cannot derive . i must just call it.

Comment: Actually assume that an instance of B created in a way that out of my control. now i must find it... i can't  define it my self and then call it's method .  may be you should think about an instance of B created instant and silently after i press "Run Button" !!! sorry i don't know how explain my situation...

Comment: Maybe include your Run Button code above. Can't understand how you don't have access to the instantiated class

Answer (score 1):

`C` don't know about `B` so there is no reason for you to have an inheritance relations between the two:

```
public class C:A
{
    public void call(){
       B b = new B();
       b.chop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate duplication. Currently you have duplication of `call()` implementation in B and C. Extracting common base class for them will do the job:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void chop()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class D: A
{
    public override void chop(){
       print("b.chop");
    }   
}

public class B: D
{
   // other members specific to B
}

public class C: D
{   
   // other members specific to C
}
```

Both B and C will print `b.chop`

Answer (score 0):

please note that I'm Writing the code in java, just see the logic and implement the same in C#.

```
Class A
Class B extends A
Class C extends A

public class A
 {
  public virtual void chop(){

 }
}

public class B extends A
{
 @override 
   public void chop(){
   print("b.chop");
}
}

public class C extends A
{
   public void call(A a ){    //make themethod parametarized and pass the object
   a.chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
}
}
```

and when you will create the object of B class do it like

```
 A a = new B();
 C c = new C();
 c.call(a);
```

you will get the required output!!!

Comment: please ignore the syntax error. I'm just trying to convey my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since B and C are not related directly to each other, you would not be able to call the method in B from C, except through an object of B in C.

As far as I can think, you have 3 options:

1. C uses an object of B:

   ```
   public class A
   {
       public virtual void chop(){

       }
   }

   public class B:A
   {
       public override void chop(){
          print("b.chop");
       }
   }

   public class C:A
   {
       public void call(){
          var b = new B();
          b.chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Both B & C inherit from an intermediate class:

   ```
   public class A
   {
       public virtual void chop(){

       }
   }

   public class D:A         //taken from Sergey Berezovskiy answer, just for the sake of completeness.
   {
       public override void chop(){
          print("b.chop");
       }
   }

   public class B:D
   {

   }

   public class C:D
   {
       public void call(){
          chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
       }
   }
   ```
3. C inherits from B:

   ```
   public class A
   {
       public virtual void chop(){

       }
   }

   public class B:A
   {
       public override void chop(){
          print("b.chop");
       }
   }

   public class C:B
   {
       public void call(){
          chop();// Iwanted to print : b.chop 
       }
   }
   ```